# CKEDITOR jumps to top after editing a link

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

If I edit a link in a CKEDITOR-textarea, the cursor always jumps to the top, before the first letter of the content.
This issue only appears in IE, but only on my page. If I go to the CKEDITOR-demopage, it works as required.

I've been searching for similar issues, but didn't find anything. Anybody knows a solution for this?

Edit:
I found the problem: I've got a custom plugin to change my links, this plugin uses `element.setValue()` to replace the value of the link, this function does the jump to the top. I've also tried setHtml() and setText(), but it's the same problem.

Edit 2: Forgot to add my code:
**plugin.js**

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('previewLink', {
    icons: 'previewLink',
    init: function(editor){
        editor.addCommand('previewLinkDialog', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('previewLinkDialog'));

        editor.ui.addButton('previewLink', {
            label: 'Preview Link einfügen',
            command: 'previewLinkDialog',
            toolbar: 'insert'
        });

        CKEDITOR.dialog.add('previewLinkDialog', this.path + 'dialogs/previewLink.js');

        editor.on('doubleclick', function(evt){
            var element = evt.data.element;
            if(!element.isReadOnly()){
                if(element.is('a')){
                    editor.openDialog('previewLinkDialog');
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**dialogs/previewLink.js**

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('previewLinkDialog', function(editor){
    return {
        title: 'Preview Link einfügen',
        minWidth: 400,
        minHeight: 200,

        contents: [
            {
                id: 'tab-basic',
                label: 'Basic Settings',
                elements: [
                    {
                        type: 'text',
                        id: 'text',
                        label: 'Text',
                        validate: CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.notEmpty("Bitte füllen Sie das Text-Feld aus"),
                        setup: function(element){
                            this.setValue(element.getText());
                        },
                        commit: function(element){
                            // The problem happens here
                            element.setText(this.getValue());
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'text',
                        id: 'link',
                        label: 'Link',
                        validate: CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.notEmpty("Bitte füllen Sie das Link-Feld aus"),
                        setup: function(element){
                            //this.setValue(element.getAttribute('data-cke-pa-onclick'));
                            this.setValue(element.getAttribute('data-cke-saved-href'));
                        },
                        commit: function(element){
                            //element.setAttribute('data-cke-pa-onclick', this.getValue());
                            element.setAttribute('data-cke-saved-href', this.getValue());
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        type : 'checkbox',
                        id : 'popup',
                        label : 'In Popup öffnen',
                        'default' : 'checked',
                        onclickString: "openPopUp(this.href, '', iScreen.windowWidth, iScreen.windowHeight, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0); return false;",
                        setup: function(element){
                            this.setValue(element.getAttribute('data-cke-pa-onclick') == this.onclickString);
                        },
                        commit: function(element){
                            if(this.getValue() === true){
                                var onclick = this.onclickString;
                                element.setAttribute('data-cke-pa-onclick', this.onclickString);
                            }
                            else {
                                element.removeAttribute('data-cke-pa-onclick');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],

        onShow: function() {
            var selection = editor.getSelection(),
                element = selection.getStartElement();
            if (element)
                element = element.getAscendant('a', true);

            if (!element || element.getName() != 'a' || element.data('cke-realelement')){
                element = editor.document.createElement('a');
                this.insertMode = true;
            }
            else
                this.insertMode = false;

            this.element = element;

            if (!this.insertMode)
                this.setupContent( this.element );
        },

        onOk: function() {
            var dialog = this,
                link = this.element;

            this.commitContent(link);

            if (this.insertMode)
                editor.insertElement(link);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: if on their page works OK than you should update your plugin. Keep an eye on the Developer Tools console for possible errors.

Comment: The problem is, that i've got a custom plugin. See edited text for details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this problem is that with the [`setText`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-method-setText) call you're removing a node that keeps the selection. As a fallback IE will move the selection to the beginning which causes your editor to scroll.

You have a couple of options here.

### Select edited link

In your dialog commit function, make sure that the selection is placed on the element that you want to be selected. You can do it with a single line.

```
commit: function(element){
    // The problem happens here
    element.setText(this.getValue());
    editor.getSelection().selectElement( element );
}
```

Note that despite your initial caret position, it will always be changed to select the entire link. Still, **this is a solution I'd recommend** because of its simplicity.

### Store a bookmark

If a precise caret position is a crucial factor for you, then you could use bookmarks to store the "snapshot" of the selection before you modify the DOM, to restore it later.

In this particular case you need to use [`bookmark2`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range-method-createBookmark2) API (standard bookmarks would get removed by DOM manipulation).

```
commit: function(element){
    // The problem happens here.
    var sel = editor.getSelection(),
        // Create a bookmark of selection before node modification.
        bookmark = sel.getRanges().createBookmarks2( false ),
        rng;

    // Update element inner text.
    element.setText(this.getValue());

    try {
        // Attempt to restore the bookmark.
        sel.selectBookmarks( bookmark );
    } catch ( e ) {
        // It might fail in case when we had sth like: "<a>foo bar ^baz<a>" and the new node text is shorter than the former
        // caret offset, it will throw IndexSizeError in this case. If so we want to
        // manually put it at the end of the string.
        if ( e.name == 'IndexSizeError' ) {
            rng = editor.createRange();
            rng.setStartAt( element, CKEDITOR.POSITION_BEFORE_END );
            rng.setEndAt( element, CKEDITOR.POSITION_BEFORE_END );
            sel.selectRanges( [ rng ] );
        }
    }
}
```

If you need any more information see the [`range`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range) and [`selection`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.selection) docs.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem, I suggest you may try to set the position of the cursor after calling the function that cause the problem?

```
// do before your custom action
var ranges = editor.getSelection().getRanges(); 
// .............your code ................
// after your custom page
ranges[0].setStart(element.getFirst(), 0);
ranges[0].setEnd(element.getFirst(), 0); //cursor
```

Reference:
http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/Any-way-to-getset-cursorcaret-location